# Java Spring: how to run two different cronjobs simultaneously?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, cron, scheduled-tasks

First of all, sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find a similar question so I decided to ask it myself.

Let's say I have two different cron jobs like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 * * * *")
private void sleepForDays() {
    while(true) sleep();
}

@Scheduled(cron= "0 * * * * *")
private void logHello() {
   log("hello!");
}
```

I have a function that runs for days, which is triggered every 30th minute of hour. (0 30 * * * *) Let's name it `sleepForDays()`.

I have another function that is supposed to log hello each minute. Lets name it `logHello()`.

**Questions:**

1. Once `sleepForDays()` is started, I believe second `sleepForDays()` won't start until first one is finished. Right?
2. Once `sleepForDays()` is started, `logHello()` is not working each minute. I do logging inside this function on my production environment, and I can't see those logs on output file. Clearly it's not working while `sleepForDays()` is in execution.

**Intentions:**

1. I want different cronJobs to operate independently from each other. In other words, I don't want `sleepForDays()` to block `logHello()`.
2. I also want to avoid duplicate execution of same cronJob. If `sleepForDays()` is already executing, I don't want a second `sleepForDays()` to start.

My main point of posting this question is Question #2. Regarding similar posts in StackOverflow, I believe Question #1's answer is yes. I wanted to make sure my assumption in Question #1 is correct.

Thank you for your time!

**Edit:**

The problem is probably about the fact that I initialize `TaskScheduler` bean with default parameters. By default, `TaskScheduler` do not support multithreading for scheduled cronjobs. If I initialize TaskScheduled bean with multithreading support, will my question #1's answer still be yes?

Bean initialization is as follows:

```
@Bean
public static TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
}
```

**Edit 2: Solution**

Big thanks to contributors, I managed to run those functions concurrently, using the bean initialization below. I simply replaced `TaskScheduler` bean with this one:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler"); // i dont know what it does, i used it anyways lol
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide you configuration source code of the Jobs, Trigger and Executor? I think the behavior in question is configurable. For example if your executor has only one single worker thread, it won't ever execute multiple jobs in parallel (neither same nor different jobs).

Comment: @Selaron thank you for your concern. To be honest, I cant find anything else significant to share. Basically, there are two functions with `@Scheduled` annotation. I checked my configuration file for anything related to crons, jobs, triggers, executors, I couldn't find any relevant configuration. The configuration file is all about peripheral credentials like elasticsearch, rabbitmq and redis host/ports. I believe, if there is any configuration available, I should be using the default ones.

Comment: Actually I found a `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` bean in ApplicationConfig file. It takes no arguments btw. All properties are default I guess.

Comment: Thats helpful already as it suggests you are using the defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All @Scheduled methods share, by default, a single thread. You can modify this behavior by defining, for example, a custom [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) bean:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I found a `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` bean, initialized inside ApplicationConfig with no parameters. I believe it's quite similar to `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. I will check documentation and hopefully edit my question with the answer:)

Comment: question: If I somehow support multithreading for scheduled cronjobs, will my question #1's answer still be yes?

Comment: thanks for update! So, basically, I should **replace** `TaskScheduler` bean with your `ScheduledExecutorService` bean, right? edit: trying that atm

Comment: @AliYılmaz Yes, or  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler (my fault, both does not allow overlapping, that's why I removed the update)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the cronjob for 90 second using spring fixedrate eg.

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 90000)
public void runAfter90Second(){
```

System.out.println("dateTime: "+ LocalDateTime.now());
} code here

```
enter code here
```